# What is the axle thickness of the Kent Road Tech 700c bike?

Tags: wheels, axle

I need to know in order to find proper fitting anti theft nuts to keep the wheels from being stolen.

Answer (score 3):

I can't find "roadtech" on www.kent.bike so there's no real way to look it up in the catalog.  I could only find some pictures on [mass-market websites](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Kent-700c-Men-s-RoadTech-Road-Bike/42732935?wmlspartner=wlpa&adid=22222222227032451886&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=63410827472&wl4=pla-127089581552&wl5=9032179&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=8175035&wl11=online&wl12=42732935&wl13=&veh=sem&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI_umVltPQ3gIVg_hkCh1EhA_REAQYAiABEgJlDfD_BwE), and from the look of it, you've already got regular solid axles with hex nuts.

If I had to guess, I'd say 9mm on the front and 10mm on the rear, but that's totally a guess.

Your best bet is to measure.  Take one front nut and one rear nut to a hardware store and see what size bolt fits.  9mm and 10mm are the most likely, but 12mm and 3/8" are also possible.

The other thing you could do is just lock the wheels to the bike and park in a public place.  Those locking nuts are really expensive.